# Error through downloading bench-2.2.3 file

Tags: linux, centos, embedded-linux, blackfin

I have downloaded the `bench-2.2.3` and unzip that but still the program try to download it, how can i tell it I have it on my `Centos` and don't need to download?
Also,there is nothing in the address of tux and buildroot! how can I change the path of search for bench-2.2.3?
Please watch the below image

Thanks
[image: bench downloading error]

Comment: In (http://www.tux.org) and (http://sources.buildroot.net) there is nothing for download. How can I change its PATH for search about nbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I will answer question by my own.
I found it.
make change in below file and save it.

> buildroot->Package->nbench
>
> VI nbench.mk

and change the address of www.tux.org to a valid address of nbench-2.2.3